# Grouping millions of near similar strings together in Linq?

Tags: c#, string

I am new to Linq and am trying to convert one of my SQL queries to C# to achieve this. Let us say I have the following set of strings:

```
ABC-pqr-cv3-xa
LKJ-eqq-cb2-ya
POI-qqq-aaa-1
ABC-pqr-cv3-xb
UIO-qqq-xa
LKJ-eqq-cb2-za
POI-qqq-aaa-2
UIO-qqq-xb
LKJ-eqq-cb2-yb
POI-qqq-aaa-3
```

I want to group these strings based on whether the entire string matches except the last character. Therefore, following is the output I am expecting:

```
ABC-pqr-cv3-xa -- 1
ABC-pqr-cv3-xb -- 1

LKJ-eqq-cb2-ya -- 2
LKJ-eqq-cb2-yb -- 2

UIO-qqq-xa -- 3
UIO-qqq-xb -- 3

POI-qqq-aaa-1 -- 4
POI-qqq-aaa-2 -- 4
POI-qqq-aaa-3 -- 4

LKJ-eqq-cb2-za -- 5
```

Doing this naively would require O(n^2) comparisons. Is there a better way to achieve this? The group numbering itself is not of concern. I am currently trying this and will post an answer if I figure out an efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myLotsOfStrings.GroupBy(item => item.Substring(-1))
```

which will yield an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,string>>`, where the `IGrouping<string,string>` is an `IEnumerable<string>` of items in the group.

It is built using an `ILookup` which, when created, only iterates the source once and builds a dictionary-like structure that allows multiple values per key. It's probably going to be about as efficient as possible... more like O(N).

Given your constraints set out in the comments below, you'd probably need a Regex to do the trimming of your group key.

The regular expression:

```
(^.*-(?=\d+$))|(^.*-[^-]*(?=[^-]$))
```

would match `POI-qqq-aaa-` for `POI-qqq-aaa-123` and `POI-qqq-aaa-xv` for `POI-qqq-aaa-xva`.

So putting it all together...

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(^.*-(?=\d+$))|(^.*-[^-]*(?=[^-]$))");
myLotsOfStrings
    //for each item, create anonymous object with 2 props, the original item
    //and the Match that is returned by running the regex over the item
    .Select(item => new{item, match = regex.Match(item)})
    //for each anonymous object (with properties item and match)
    //filter out any items where the regex failed to match 
    //(e.g match.Success is not true)
    .Where(x => x.match.Success)
    //now create an IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,string>>
    //where the value of the (successful) match is used for the key (match.value)
    //and the item in the group is the item property of the anonymous
    //object created above
    .GroupBy(x => x.match.Value, x => x.item)
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: +1 Wonderful! This works perfectly fine for the case when the last character is the only one that is differing. However, how can I deal with cases where the last set of characters could be consecutive? (e.g., POI-qqq-aaa-1, POI-qqq-aaa-2 etc. in my example above). Is there a way I can pass a custom comparator somehow?

Comment: @Legend: Is this Linq2Objects or some other provider (Linq2Sql/Linq2EF)? I've assumed Linq2Objects... is this right?

Comment: This is Linq2Objects.

Comment: @Legend: so, you'd like to extend this such that contiguous strings within the existing groups are formed into sub groups? is this right?

Comment: Hmm.. Your technique works fine for every case except when there is an additional string POI-qqq-aaa-17 where its not just the last character that needs to match i.e., POI-qqq-aaa-17 should be placed into the same group as the POI-qqq-aaa-1,POI-qqq-aaa-2,POI-qqq-aaa-3.

Comment: OK, your constraints need to be a little more refined to get to the end. What are the specific constraints for items that should be grouped? Is it using the last character? Should numbers at the end get special treatment? Does the number *always* follow a dash? When there's no number, we use the last character, or do non-numeric endings also have a "sequence"? These things are not clear.

Comment: Sorry about that. The specific constraints are as follows: 1. When there is a character following the last dash (i.e., it can appear anywhere after the last dash), things with the same number should be grouped together (e.g., 1a and 1b should be grouped together but 2a should be a separate group), 2. When there is no character following the last dash, strings should be grouped together as long as they contain a number (e.g., 1,2,3,17 should all be in one group).

Comment: I am trying to understand how this is working. The regex is basically saying, capture anything that has a number following the last dash or has any other character in the end except a dash. I am unable to comprehend what exactly is happening inside the Linq statements. Would you mind shedding some light so I can learn what's happening? Again, I really appreciate you spending so much time on this.

Comment: You rock! Thanks for updating your post with comments. This helps a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the brevity of spender's answer but I thought I would add something a bit longer using the more SQL linq syntax (since that is what you are familiar with).  Most of it is setup and output :-)

```
        var d =
@"ABC-pqr-cv3-xa
LKJ-eqq-cb2-ya
POI-qqq-aaa-1
ABC-pqr-cv3-xb
UIO-qqq-xa
LKJ-eqq-cb2-za
POI-qqq-aaa-2
UIO-qqq-xb
LKJ-eqq-cb2-yb
POI-qqq-aaa-3";
        var lines = d.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var grp = from line in lines
                  group line by line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1) into g
                  select g;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var g in grp) {
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
            foreach (var s in g) {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", s);
                }
            }
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for this approach. I'm facing the same problem as the one I posed to spencer (where say, another string POI-qqq-aaa-17 is present).

Comment: That seems a bit trickier since it breaks the pattern.  You might consider using a RegEx instead of the simplier 'Length - 1'.  The performance impact of that would depend greatly on the regex used.